# Unable to create a better database structure

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a basic project to search buses from one station to another

Let I have four stations `A,B,C,D` and I have four buses `1,2,3,4`

Root of buses are

```
bus 1 : A->B->C->D
Bus 2 : A->C->D
Bus 3 : A->C->B
Bus 4 : A->B->D
```

How can I design a database for such system

I have tried

`Method 1:` I have created a table with two fields `busno` and `busroute` in bus route I want to store complete route of the bus number. but I think searching in this table will be very complex

or please suggest me a better Idea for such project

Comment: Please show us the table structure and some expample data of your `Method 1`.

Comment: may be you can create  three tables ,Bus table for holding bus info , Route table for holding route info , Mapp_Route_toBus table that will map bus to routes

Comment: I d go for 3 tables, a bus table, a bus stop table and a table where you combine them by id of bus and id of bus stop, plus probably a position where they need to stop, so you can sort it by position and get the route instantly when asking the right query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My hint is, 3 tables

### Bus

- id
- name

### Stops

- id
- name

### Route

- BusId
- StopId
- position

Comment: If I want to search trains between st1 to st2 then how would I search

Comment: `select busId from (select busId from route where stopId=st1) a join (select busId from route where stopId=st2) b on a.busId = b.busId` , uncompete position need to be considered too if one way routes

Comment: `select case when a.position < b.position then busId else null end as busId from (select busId,position from route where stopId=st1) a join (select busId,position from route where stopId=st2) b on a.busId = b.busId`

Comment: Sorry I am not able to get this query can you please explain a little bit more because I have never used the query like join

Comment: when trying to search using first reply working ok in one side but when using second reply getting error mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Answer (score 1):

for stations you may create a table that has two fields, station name and station order and you link the bus number with rows from station table.
station table example:

```
A - 1
B - 2
B - 3
```

and you link bus 1 through keys with A-1 and B-2 and that means that A is the first station and B is the second for bus 1. Also you link bus 3 with B-3 which means B is the third station for bus 3...etc.

Comment: If I want to search trains between st1 to st2 then how would I search

Comment: You take the first station and see in which paths it's located, then you take the second one and try to find it with a bigger number in the same paths you found in the first step (bigger number means the second station is after the first one in this path).

the first station may have the number 3 and the second one number 1 and it's ok cause the bus works in a circular path but if you want to find the best and the shortest path you can take the path which the absolute value of (station 2 - station1) is the least possible value

Comment: dont you think that it will use a large db space

Comment: somehow yes cause you may have A-1, A-2, A-3, B-1, B-2, B-3... but I think it's better than having 3 tables cause 2 tables will be enough

Answer (score 1):

How about this one

```
| Buses |
| id | name |

| Stations |
| id | name |

| Destinations |
| busId | stationId | priorityNo | // Where priorityNo determines where the bus should stop first.
```

The good part about this you can always add new buses and stations.

Comment: If I want to search trains between st1 to st2 then how would I search